# Soccer match statistic bar plot in R

Tags: r, annotations, bar-chart, visualization, r-plotly

I am trying to replicate such a plot preferably in R.

[Match statistic example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Mdhd.png)

I am trying to find a solution and did some work with a dummy data set.
At the moment, my result looks like this:
[own match statistic plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0GhU.png)

The dummy code I used to create this plot is this:

```
team_1 <- c(rep("team_1", 4))
team_2 <- c(rep("team_2",4))
statistics <- c("shots", "passes", 
                "offsides", "corners")
values_team_1 <- c(5, 120, 5, 2)
values_team_2 <- c(10, 400, 0, 7)

dummy_frame <- data.frame(
  team_1, statistics,
  values_team_1,
  values_team_2,
  team_2
)

dummy_frame <- dummy_frame %>%
  mutate(values_team_1_rel = values_team_1 / 
           (values_team_1 + values_team_2),
         values_team_2_rel = values_team_2 / 
           (values_team_1 + values_team_2)) 

barplot_team_1 <- plot_ly(dummy_frame,
                 x = ~ values_team_1_rel * (-1),
                 y = ~ statistics,
                 type = "bar",
                 orientation = "h",
                 name = "team_1") 

barplot_team_2 <- plot_ly(dummy_frame,
                 x = ~ values_team_2_rel,
                 y = ~ statistics,
                 type = "bar",
                 orientation = "h",
                 name = "team_2") 


subplot(barplot_team_1, barplot_team_2,
        shareY = TRUE,
        margin = 0) %>%
  layout(barmode = 'grouped',
         xaxis = list(title = "",
                      showticklabels = FALSE),
         xaxis2 = list(title = "",
                       showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(title ="",
                      showticklabels = FALSE)) %>%
  add_annotations(x = 0,
                  y = dummy_frame$statistics,
                  text = dummy_frame$statistics,
                  xref = "x",
                  yref = "y",
                  showarrow = FALSE)
```

I am having trouble to locate the annotation above of the bar. Additionally, it creates this weird space between the plots (indicated it with an arrow in the picture).
Is it even possible to create such a plot in R with plotly?
If so, what can I do to locate the text on top of the bars and prevent plotly from inserting this weird space?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to use plotly?

Comment: No, not at all. I am open to suggestions including other packages :)